# Deploying image files in a Clojure/Java environment

Tags: heroku, clojure

On Heroku, with the "ephemeral" file system, I am wondering how you would typically handle basic image files in a web development workflow. The two main questions on this would be:

1) How best to deploy them to your server environment? Should they simply be included in the git repo? If so, if you have lots of media, this can be a large git repo, with media being 99% of the repo and the source code the rest.

2) On [Heroku's site](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-faq), they say this:

> Your application source code plus built artifacts must be less than
>   200MB. Use .slugignore to prevent files in your git repo from being
>   included in the deployed package

Does this mean the git repo cannot exceed 200 MB? So this includes image files and other non-source files needed for web development?

3) What is the disk space quota on Heroku? There is no mention I can find of this. Unless the 200 MB above is basically a disk quota.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would honestly recommend that you store them in another resource. I currently use [Cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/) for this type of purpose. The terms are reasonable and there's a "free" tier that I think most people would be hard pressed to pass unless they website they're creating really takes off in eyeballs/useage. At that point, you have other problems/joys. As far as other large resources, there's always S3 from Amazon. It's cheap, fast and dependable.

Due note, I'm not advocating not placing your raw js or css in Git. Those I'd keep in your app for now unless you can find a free CDN.